# Assorted jQuery questions

Tags: javascript, jquery

1.) What's the difference between these two queries, exactly?

```
$( "#orderedlist li" )
$( "#orderedlist>li" )
```

2.) In the jQuery file itself there is a function that returns the following:

```
function now(){
    return +new Date;
}
```

What does that mean?  I've never seen +new before.

<strike>3.) In a brief skimming of a tutorial, I observed the following samples:</strike>

```
// use this to reset a single form
$( "#reset" ).click( function()
{
    $( "form" )[0].reset();
});

// use this to reset several forms at once
$( "#reset" ).click( function()
{
    $( "form" ).each( function()
    {
        this.reset();
    });
});
```

When I try to reference my own queries by array indexes, they don't seem to work.  Yet this example clearly did when I tested it.  What could I be doing wrong?

**Edit:** I'll put this one into its own question soon.
**Edit 2:** Actually I may be able to debug it myself.  Hang on...

I have guesses to each of these, but short of dissecting the jQuery file itself in full, I'm not completely certain what's at work here.  Help appreciated.

Comment: I think these questions should be asked separately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Question #1**:

- `#orderedlist li` is a "descendant selector": an `li` anywhere within an `#orderedlist`.
- `#orderedlist>li` is a "child selector": an `li` which is a direct child of an `#orderedlist`.

**Question #2**:

That's using the unary plus operator - it's equivalent to:

```
return Number(new Date);
```

see: http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/unary-add/ - it gives the number of milliseconds since the UNIX epoch.

<del>**Question #3**:</del>

I don't know about this one.  Could you post a minimal failing example?